# Debug Ionic Webview on Google Nexus

Tags: android, webview, ionic-framework

I have an application using Ionic I have followed all of the guides to be able to debug this webview but it doesn't show up in chrome://inspect#devices. Tabs in chrome do show up but apps running in ionic webview do not.

I am running Android 4.4.4 I even tried adding this

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) { 
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true); 
}
```

To platforms\android\src\com\ionicframework\myapp\MainActivity.java and still nothing. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Need to install the actual APK to be able to debug the application

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/02/properly-testing-ionic-framework-mobile-application/